# How to have light build with rehype-raw plugin installed with nextjs?

Tags: next.js

I have added a video in my markdown file and when I run **npm run build** the bundle size
is somewhat big

[image: build]

Can some one give me suggestion for
having  a light build with rehype-raw plugin installed ?

I am using ReactMarkdown to render the markdown files

```
<ReactMarkdown components={customRenderers} rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]} linkTarget="_blank">
                {posts.content}
</ReactMarkdown>
```

Comment: I'd recommend you [analyze your bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next/bundle-analyzer). This will help you to find out what exactly is increasing the bundle size, use that information to optimize your pages.

Comment: On a production grade online shop with tons of custom logic our biggest page is 136kb. Try to leverage server components to your advantage if possible. Bundle size affects your load times and so directly influences the happiness of your users.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rehype-raw I am not able to integrate rehype-raw with ReactMarkdown check the example.js .

Comment: In my case ReactMarkdown is using customRenderers while example.js in rehype-raw is using a different approach to read markdown file . How to integrate both the approaches ? How did you add video in markdown files in your production grade online shop ?